# jQuery toggle class

Tags: jquery, class, html, audio, toggle

I'm having trouble adding in jQuery's toggleClass function into the rest of my code. The page has several HTML5 audio tags on it which are controlled via jQuery. I attempted to add the toggle function to my jQuery audio control function, but it's not adding the class and subsequently the audio control doesn't work.. so I suppose it's some weird syntax error.

What do you guys recommend? Below is a jsFiddle and a my (unfortunately) weak attempt :)

http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/FTfSq/10/

HTML:

```
<div id="music_right">
    <div class="thumbnail" id="paparazzi">
        <a class="playback">
            <img class="play" src="http://www.lucisz.com/imgs/play.png" />
        </a>
        <audio>
         <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_paparazzisnlmix.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
            <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_paparazzisnlmix.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
            Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail" id="danceinthedark">
        <a class="playback">
            <img class="play" src="http://www.lucisz.com/imgs/play.png" />
        </a>
        <audio>
         <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_danceinthedark.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
            <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_danceinthedark.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
            Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail" id="bornthisway">
        <a class="playback">
            <img class="play" src="http://www.lucisz.com/imgs/play.png" />
        </a>
        <audio>
         <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_bornthisway.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
            <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_bornthisway.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
            Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
        </audio>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var curPlaying;
$(function() {
    $(".playback").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var song = $(this).next('audio')[0];
        song.toggleClass("playing");
        if(song.paused){
            song.play();
            if(curPlaying) $("audio", "#"+curPlaying)[0].pause();
        } else {
            song.pause();
            }
        curPlaying = $(this).parent()[0].id;
    });
});

//the function below works, but doesn't have the add/remove class functions

var curPlaying;
$(function() {
    $(".playback").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var song = $(this).next('audio')[0];
        if (song.paused) {
            song.play();
            if (curPlaying) $("audio", "#" + curPlaying)[0].pause();
        } else {
            song.pause();
        }
        curPlaying = $(this).parent()[0].id;
    });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`.

Comment: @Blender What context are you thinking? adding a class that signifies a track as playing.. and from there change the image source?

Comment: Yep, that's what I'd do.

Comment: @Blender. Clever, I dig it. Thank you

Comment: I have got to stop answering questions with comments...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), as it'll clean up your code quite a bit and allow you to use CSS to perform all that layout work:

```
$('thumbnail').toggle(function(){
    $('.play', this).removeClass('pausing');
    $('.play', this).addClass('playing');
}, function(){
    $('.play', this).addClass('pausing');
    $('.play', this).removeClass('playing');
});
```

Comment: after pondering for a bit, I can use this idea to serve another purpose simultaneously, but to do so need to add it to the audio tag that's playing. I'm going to rewrite the question with the purpose of adding the class within that function. One moment.

Answer (score 15):

```
$('thumbnail').toggleClass('pausing playing');
```

**ToggleClass**: Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the switch argument.

Comment: A very clever implementation of toggleClass() :)