# Toggle and re-Toggle class on Click to make pretty Checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

This seems something I shouldnt have to waste a question on, but I can't get it to work!

I'm trying to make a pretty checkbox using a `<span>` with a background icon and a hidden checkbox.

My HTML is

```
<span class="checkedBox" id="mailing_Check"></span>
<input type="checkbox" id="mailing" /> <!--(currently not hidden for testing)-->
```

CSS is simple:

```
.checkedBox { background: url('../images/iconLine.png'); background-position: -550px, 0px; display: inline-block; width: 25px; height: 25px }
.unCheckedBox { background: url('../images/iconLine.png'); background-position: -575px, 0px; display: inline-block; width: 25px; height: 25px }
```

I need to bind an onClick handler to the checkedBox item, toggle/flip the class to unCheckedBox and set the checkbox to checked.

Now, I have various long winded ways of doing this, but am trying to do it using jQuery toggle, or toggleClass and I can't get it to work properly.

Just working with flipping the CSS class for now...

```
$('.checkedBox, unCheckedBox').live('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('checkedBox').toggleClass('checkedBox');
});
```

That will flip it once, but is not binding properly, when I click the second time, it has no effect.

I've tried using this example; [jQuery toggle class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723380/jquery-toggle-class)

But that doesn't seem to want to work, also various other Googled results, but for some reason I am struggling.

I want to keep the code to a minimum using the minimum requirement of variables, like I say, I have some long winded method using if/else logic, but I figured jQuery should make it easier!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're modifying the exact same CSS style properties on your two CSS rules (`.checkedBox` and `.unCheckedBox`), I imagine that you don't have to toggle the `.checkedbox` class, because the other just overrides it.

Even better, you can just have a class that marks all your "pretty" checkboxes, and then another that modifies the style from the default.

Maybe something like:

#### CSS

```
.pretty-checkbox { /* default style rules */ }
.pretty-checkbox.checked { /* style rules when checked */ }
```

Then you can just worry about toggling the `.checked` class.

```
$('.pretty-checkbox').live('click', function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
});
```

Comment: Awesome! That's brilliant, I knew there was something dead simple out there!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
$('.checkedBox, .unCheckedBox').live('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('checkedBox unCheckedBox');//toggle the class
    $(this).next().click();//click the checkbox
});
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/3uu2M/

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
  $(this).toggleClass('checkedBox').toggleClass('unCheckedBox');
```

You had `checkedBox` listed twice

This might be easier to read or you can combine the calls to `toggleClass()` and separate with a space.

```
  $(this).toggleClass('checkedBox unCheckedBox');
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Arrghh.... whilst you're right, and I thank you for spotting the deliberate error... it still doesn't work!

Comment: @Jamie - I'm betting the problem is somewhere in code you are not posting then.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the answer from richardneililagan gives me what I need really simply, so I am going to go with that. Thanks :)