# JQuery add/remove class onClick

Tags: jquery

Open submenu on click, close on next click - that's what i would like to achive.  example is [this page](http://jquery-plugins.net/page/6) (submenu under 'follow' link).
it opens submenu (adds class 'open'), but not closing. stucked... :(

my html:

```
<ul id="toggle"><li>
<a href="#">Menu</a>
<ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a href="#">2017</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2003</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#toggle li').on('click', function(){
$(this).removeClass('open').addClass('open');
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/32pv6xz8/7/

Comment: 7 answers so far, all suggest `toggleClass`, anybody left?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery toggle class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723380/jquery-toggle-class)

Comment: @Vohuman not all ;-), at least not only

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the function `toggleClass()` for this:

```
$('#toggle li').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('open')
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fjmnqx7e/)

Here is a slightly different approach:

jQuery

```
$('#toggle li').on('click', function () {
     $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
 });
```

CSS

```
#toggle li ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/p8cv98h2/)

For preventing the redirect you have to use `.preventDefault()`:

```
 $('#toggle li:has(#dropdown)').on('click', function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).parents('#dropdown').length > 0) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

I`m not sure if this is the cleanest or best approach, but it is working.

If you want to save the url for further use (e.g. redirectuing via `window.location`) you can assign the href-attribute to a variable:

```
var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

[Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/x3vjrn4j/)

**Reference**

[.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

[.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Comment: i like very much this 'different approach' to my question. i will use it.

Comment: but, i would like to 'develope it further'. in my handwritten html code anchor tag doesn't have an url, but usually it does:

'...
<li>
<a href="http://www.myhomepage.com/somecategory">Menu</a>
<ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
...'

so, my question is: on click, how to 'force' to open a submenu not go to that url if anchor has an url?

Comment: @Gallex if one of the answers had helped you, feel free to accept any

Comment: a bit rushed, not brilliant yet. now all anchors not redirecting, but i need only this anchor which has submenu
[link]http://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/0akdz4ow/
anchors in submenu, also need to redirect

Comment: yes, submenu anchors now working, but main menu do not
http://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/0akdz4ow/4/

Comment: now working. 
empiric, but could this done without #dropdown, just 
$('#toggle li:has(ul)').on..
at least in my example not working:
 http://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/0akdz4ow/6/

Comment: @Gallex try this instead `$(event.target).parents('ul.dropdown-menu')`

Comment: so, without adding class or id to submenu, it's not possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use `toggleClass` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#toggle li').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toggle li').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open')('open');
    });
});
```

Check out [the corrected jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32pv6xz8/8/) :)

What you did wrong was, that you chained the add and remove functions:

```
$(this).removeClass('open').addClass('open');
```

What this will do is removing the class 'open' and (when this is finsihed) add the class 'open' again. This caused, that the class would not dissapear.

Answer (score 2):

Use [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function in jquery

```
$('#toggle li').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('open')
});
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gayanstar/32pv6xz8/10/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#toggle li').on('click', function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

use the toggleClass() function.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gayanstar/32pv6xz8/10/)

Answer (score 1):

it's because you are removing the class then adding it...so it will ALWAYS be added

```
$(this).removeClass('open');
```

to close it .

Use this instead

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#toggle li').on('click', function(){
$(this).toggleClass('open');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toggle li').on('click', function(){
         $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/32pv6xz8/9/)