# JQuery add and remove class onclick

Tags: jquery

I wanted to show and remove css class when the button is clicked, i know there's a solution using `toggleclass()` but i want to add class using `onClick` function.

Here's the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".main-header-menu-toggle").click(function () {
      jQuery("body").addClass('ast-main-header-nav-open');
   });
});
```

I want to add class to body, it worked when i click on the button but when i again close the button it doesn't remove the class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery add/remove class onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391465/jquery-add-remove-class-onclick)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not remove because there is no code for remove class from body.
Please use the above code as following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".main-header-menu-toggle").click(function () {
      jQuery("body").toggleClass('ast-main-header-nav-open');
   });
});
```

By using toggleClass method, a class will be added on first click and will be removed when you again click on the button.

Try this with hasClass method if it is not working for Safari

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(".main-header-menu-toggle").click(function () {
  if(jQuery("body").hasClass('ast-main-header-nav-open')){
    jQuery("body").removeClass('ast-main-header-nav-open')
  }else{
    jQuery("body").addClass('ast-main-header-nav-open');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color:green;
  display:block;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
body.ast-main-header-nav-open{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="main-header-menu-toggle">Click me!</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Please try this once:
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(".main-header-menu-toggle").click(function () {
  if(jQuery("body").hasClass('ast-main-header-nav-open')){
    jQuery("body").removeClass('ast-main-header-nav-open')
  }else{
    jQuery("body").addClass('ast-main-header-nav-open');
  }
 });
});

Comment: Please mark my answer if it fixed your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the friends said above, you can do it in a simple way.

Deletion is triggered when the `hasClass` function returns true. When it returns to false, the insertion process is triggered. We have done this with the if condition.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".main-header-menu-toggle").click(function() {
    ($('body').hasClass('ast-main-header-nav-open')) ? $('body').removeClass('ast-main-header-nav-open'): $('body').addClass('ast-main-header-nav-open')
  });
});
```

```css
.ast-main-header-nav-open {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<a class="main-header-menu-toggle">Click</a>
</body>
```